# Let \numquestions\ don't count the bonusqestions

Tags: exam

I'd like to use \numquestions and \numparts without them counting the bonusquestions and -parts just like \numpoints does. How can I achieve this?

To use an example; I want the following to say "*This exams contains 2 questions and a bonusquestion.*"

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}
This exams contains \numquestions\ questions and a bonusquestion.

    \begin{questions}
    \question[100]
    Is this the first question?
    \question[100]
    Is this the second question?
    \bonusquestion[100]
    Does this question count?
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `totcount` and the commands `\qquestion` and `\bbonusquestion` instead of `\question` and `\bonusquestion`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
    
%****************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{q}
\setcounter{q}{0}
\newtotcounter{b}
\setcounter{b}{0}
\newcommand{\qquestion}[0]{\stepcounter{q}\question}
\newcommand{\bbonusquestion}[0]{\stepcounter{b}\bonusquestion}
%****************************** 
    
\begin{document}
    
This exams contains \total{q}\ question(s) and \total{b}\ bonusquestion(s).
    
    \begin{questions}
        \qquestion[100]
        Is this the first question?
        \qquestion[100]
        Is this the second question?
        \bbonusquestion[100]
        Does this question count?
        \bbonusquestion[100]
        Does this question count?       
    \end{questions}
    
\end{document}
```

Inspired in [count the number of questions separately ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139847/161015)

Comment: Splendid! That works fine. Thanks a a lot.